# How to extract couple of tables from site using selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, python-3.7

Greeting all

i am trying to extract tables from this site https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/silvermoon/category/battlepets but i am having some difficulties with that. my code and whatever i used failed to bring up any result:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

def getbrowser():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver 
def scrape(): # create scrape engine from scratch
    driver = getbrowser()
    start = time.time()
    site1="https://theunderminejournal.com/#eu/silvermoon/category/battlepets"
    driver.get(site1)
    time.sleep(10)
    tbody = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
    #cell = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr").text
    for tr in tbody:
       td = tbody.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr") 
       print (td)
    driver.close() 

scrape()
```

my goal is to extract the name and the first price from each pet (from all the tables) and create a table with these two values.

generally i am building a scrape bot that will compare the prices from two servers....
i know that my scraping skills are too low , can you please point me where i could find something to read or watch to improve myself.

thanks again for your time

Comment: Have you taken look at the requests? Is there calls being made to a API? Or something like that? Probably a easier way to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the names and prices in 2 lists, and use their value in order, just replace the print command with whatever you want

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='name'] a")
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(":nth-child(4)[class='price'] span")
i = 0
for x in names
    print (x.text)
    print (prices[i].text)
    i+=1
```

hope it helps.

Comment: It's better to use `zip` instead of counter that need to be incremented on each iteration: `for name, price in zip(names, prices): print(name.text, price.text)`

Comment: didn't know it was that simple to do a zip operation in python! in c# they are so ugly and code unfriendly that i avoid them.